# how can i get text in selectbox not value

Tags: javascript

```js
$('[name="campaign_template"]').on('click', function () {
  console.log($(this).val());     
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox" for="id_campaign_template_1">
            <input type="checkbox" name="campaign_template" id="id_campaign_template_1" value="1">campaign_template
        </label>
    
        <label class="checkbox" for="id_campaign_template_2">
            <input type="checkbox" name="campaign_template" id="id_campaign_template_2" value="2">campaign_template2
        </label>
```

> I want to get `campaign_template` and `campaign_template2` when checkbox checked

When I using this way i got '1' and '2' but i want to get "text" not value...

how can i get this text??

Comment: Do you mean you want to get text in `label` or the input name ?

Comment: use ``.text()`` instead of ``.val()``

Comment: @NotABot i tried it but it doesn't work :( `text()` return empty value

Comment: ....this.nextSibling.textContent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it

```
  $('[name="campaign_template"]').on('click', function () {
        console.log($(this).parent().text());

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you mean?

```
$('[name="campaign_template"]').on('click', function () {
        console.log($(this)[0].getAttribute('name'));

    })
```